# Who is a vs. b in git diff when comparing working tree to a remote repo?

Tags: git

I blindly used 'git add' over a directory while resolving merge conflicts, and I've since discovered that some of the conflicts in that directory were 'deleted by them' cases that I wanted to honor -- to figure out if a particular file assets/thing.h has been accidentally added as an effective new file with respect to the remote upstream branch origin/master (and should be 'git rm'ed), I tried the following:

$ git diff origin/master -- assets/thing.h

```
diff --git a/assets/thing.h b/assets/thing.h
new file mode 100644
index 000000000..5a3d5b3de
--- /dev/null
+++ b/assets/thing.h
@@ -0,0 +1,167 @@
+....stuff
```

Who is 'a' and who is 'b' in this scenario?  I'm guessing 'a' is the named origin/master branch and 'b' is my working tree, and that therefore this confirms assets/thing.h was a 'deleted by them' case that I erroneously added back, but it's not clear from the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you ran it, a would be origin/master and b is your current working tree.

And in your special case, in origin/master the file does not exist, whereas in your working tree it does exist,